# How do I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8

How do I do this without a CD or USB? I'm more familiar with Windows so I would like to use that as well as Ubuntu.

I have Ubuntu currently.

Comment: Are you asking how to install Windows alongside Ubuntu? Have you tried searching for answers using your favorite search engine? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this without a USB/CD.. and I don't want to use them. Yes, windows alongside Ubuntu please

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to install an operating system without using an installation medium. I don't think you'd want to set up a PXE server if you don't want to use CD...

Comment: Although you could maybe try to boot the Windows ISO through Grub. Not sure if you'll actually be able to install it this way though. But that's a lot of hassle. Plus you obviously still need a legitimate copy of Windows 8, if that's what you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install windows first  [Hope this help](http://www.howtogeek.com/214571/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-pc/) all you have to do is customize a partition for linux system and while insatlling i think it make it automatically dual boot .. anyway read the article it will help

Comment: Elle, assume that that link will die in the future (it happens at it is called linkrot). After that not much of an answer will be left. Please put all relevant parts in an answer.

Comment: Secondly, I do not see that article touch on the key part **without a CD or USB**.

Comment: mmm try to install Grub on your pc then by grub customize it